# Im getting this error: variables should be passed by reference in bindParam method....(but not always??)

Tags: php, pdo

Im doing a basic insert with pdo, and Im not having my sucess message when I submit my form.

But neither was having no error, so I use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in top of my code.

And Im getting one error now: : Only variables should be passed by reference in  `$insert->bindParam(9, convert_datetime($f['date']));`.

This error is quite enlightening, however, I do not understand why I'm having this error, because in other parts, for example to insert categories, I am using the function in my bindParam and it is working fine..

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admins(name, email, pass, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");  
$insert->bindParam(1, $f['name']);
$insert->bindParam(2, $f['email']);
$insert->bindParam(3, $f['pass']);
$insert->bindParam(4, convert_datetime($f['date']));
$insert->execute();


if($i_a->rowCount() >=1){   
    echo '<div>Admin inserted with sucess</div>';
}
```

My function convert_datetime()

```
function convert_datetime($date_received){
    $english = array("...");
    $spanish = array("...");
    $result_date = str_ireplace ($english , $spanish, $date_received);
    $date_received = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $result_date);
    $date_received = $date_received->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    return $date_received;
```

Comment: `bindParam` is intended for output variables; whereas `bindValue` is meant for passing data *to* your database.

Comment: Sorry, I delete some columns for the question and I forget to delete that comma! I will update with my convert_datetime function!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, I found my problem now.

It seems that the problem was not related to my function inside my bindParam method.

My admins table have an column "avatar" that is defined as not null (`avatar varchar(255) NOT NULL,`),
and I was inserting my admin without select any avatar image.

So I just needed to change in my database my avatar definiton to   `avatar varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,,` and everything is working fine now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 for finding the solution yourself. I was almost certain it had something to do with the way the date/time was converted. Another happy ending ;)

Answer (score 1):

Arguments except the first are passed by reference. This means they must be variables, and not strings. Try this

```
$date = convert_datetime($f['date']);
$insert->bindParam(4, $date);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that at first when I get my error, but also dont works!

Comment: Use $insert->bindvalue instead of $insert->bindParam.